# jquery treeview expand given node

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Im building ul li list dynamically on the serverside code. How can I determine which node should be expanded when page is loaded ?

Im using plugin: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-treeview/

thank You very much for help

Answer (score 1):

It looks like they are open by default, but if you set `class="closed"` on the `<li>` tag, it will be collapsed.

```
<li class="closed">
```